# What Rebus transport should I use for running in Docker, but not Azure

Tags: docker, msmq, rebus

I try to set up a Docker container for an ASP.NET Core/net47 application that uses Rebus with MSMQ. But it doesn't seem to be possible to use MSMQ with Docker.

The application is not hosted on Azure - and it does have to communicate with external services via the bus, and they do not share a database - so it can't be SQL Server transport either, I guess.

So I wonder... what I my options with Rebus?

Answer (score 1):

Well.... I guess your best option at the moment is to pull down a Docker image with RabbitMQ in it.

But since I'm not a Docker kind of guy, I cannot give you any further instructions besides that.

Since this question reaches beyond Rebus and far into Docker territory, it would be awesome if someone well-versed in Docker stuff would chime in.